# Multiplication of selected columns by a given vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been struggling with a task in R for some time, which seems to be easy.

suppose this is my sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(2,2,7),b=c(1,4,3),c=c(9,5,3))
v <- c(1,2,3)
```

now I would like to multiply each column by the corresponding vector element e.g. first column by `v[1]`, second column by `v[2]`etc..

expected output:

```
  a b  c
1 2 2 27
2 2 8 15
3 7 6  9
```

The target data is much larger and consists of integers and floating point numbers.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sweep`:

```
sweep(df, 2, v, FUN="*")
```

Second option is `mapply`:

```
mapply(`*`, df, v)
```

Or with transposing:

```
t(t(df)*v)
```

Comment: Here's another for good measure: `df * matrix(rep(v, each=3), 3, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```r
apply(df, 1, function(x) x * v) |> t()
```

or

```r
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x * v))
```

Comment: I'm getting error: Error: unexpected '>' in:
"  x * v
}) |>"

Comment: The native pipe operator (`|>`) can only be used in R version >= 4.1.0 and RStudio v >= 1.4. See: https://www.rstudio.com/blog/rstudio-v1-4-update-whats-new/

Answer (score 1):

You can try `col`

```
> v[col(df)] * df
  a b  c
1 2 2 27
2 2 8 15
3 7 6  9
```